# How can I put an Add button when record is empty in MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is my code.

**Code:**

```
@model PagedList<Repository.IMCargo.IMPORTAWB>
@using MvcAjaxPager

@{
    List<Repository.IMCargo.AWBSECTION82> entity = ViewBag.PossibleDone;
}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{  
<tr>
    <td>@item.AWBNO
    </td>
    <td>@item.AIRLINENAME
    </td>
    <td>@item.CARGODATE
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

I want to put an Add button in the CargoDate's `<td>` if the `CARGODATE` is empty, and show the date if it has a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.AWBNO
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.AIRLINENAME
        </td>
        <td>
            @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.CARGODATE))
            {
                <input type="button" value="add" />
            }
            else{
                @item.CARGODATE
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Thank you and yes it was not nullabe Datetime and it was giving errors editing it as nullabe and your solution worked for me thumbs up if you tell how to make it http post as I want to take input from user when it's empty in list page.

Comment: @ShahAbdullah place the input inside a <form> and place a submit button too. In the form's action mention the action method like `<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")" >`. Also in the controller you need to place `[HttpPost]` above your action method.

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of the `CARGODATE` property? If it's a `DateTime?`, you can put this inside the `<td>` tag:

```
@if (item.CARGODATE.HasValue)
{
    @item.CARGODATE.Value.ToString()
}
else
{
    <input type="button" value="Add" />
}
```

And, if it's a `string`, use this:

```
@if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.CARGODATE))
{
    <input type="button" value="Add" />
}
else
{
    @item.CARGODATE
}
```

Comment: Thank you and yes it was not nullabe Datetime and it was giving errors editing it as nullabe and your solution worked for me thumbs up if you tell how to make it http post as I want to take input from user when it's empty in list page.